# Getting count of foreign keys and joining to another list?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, foreign-keys

I have two tables, `lists` and `items`

`Lists` table looks like this and

[image]

the `items` table looks like this

[image]

I am trying to query the database to get the below result,

```
| list       | count |
|------------|-------|
| my list    | 1     |
| my list 2  | 5     |
```

I could get the count with

```
SELECT count(items.list_id) as count
from items
group by list_id
```

when joining the list to this query, the counts are getting wrong. What can be the query to get the correct results? my database is sqlite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking to your sample seems you need  a join  between the tables

```
    SELECT list.name,  count(items.list_id) as count
    from list
    inner join  items on list.id = items.list_id 
    group by list.name
```